# Get data after # (hash) in PHP

Tags: php, authentication, post, get

Example: https://WBSITE_LINK.com/#access_token=1b6e37716abdh&state=state123&scope=profile%20booking&token_type=bearer&expires_in=15552000

This link is received after auth. How I get access_token?

Comment: You can also get value by js

Comment: Welcome on SO. If you need more help, provide us with more details such as how do you build the URL, what problem do you have with it, what have you tried so far (code).

Answer (score 1):

Replace the `#` with `?` and then you can access it via `$_GET` array such as:

```
$token = $_GET['access_token']; // will held 1b6e37716abdh
$state = $_GET['state']; // will held state123
// and so on.
```

Note: if it is sent from a form then change the form method to POST and all will be available in `$_POST` array and hidden from the URL.

```
<form method="POST" ...>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use regular expressions if the link is not to your page (and $_GET is not possible).

https://regex101.com/r/zfrBSk/1

```
$re = '/access_token=(.*?)(&|$)/';
$str = 'https://wbsite_link.com/#access_token=1b6e37716abdh&state=state123&scope=profile%20booking&token_type=bearer&expires_in=15552000';

preg_match($re, $str, $match);

// Print the token:
Echo $match[1];
```

https://3v4l.org/e54GC

Answer (score 0):

Another option could be to use [explode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php) and use multiple delimiters (#,&,=):

```
$subject = "https://WBSITE_LINK.com/#access_token=1b6e37716abdh&state=state123&scope=profile%20booking&token_type=bearer&expires_in=15552000";
$a = explode("#", $subject);
if (isset($a[1])) {
    $b = explode("&", $a[1]);
    if (isset($b[0])) {
        $c = explode("=", $b[0]);
        if (isset($c[1])) {
            echo $c[1];
        }
    }
}
```

[Output](https://3v4l.org/f8sIM)

An alternative regex could be to use [\K](http://php.net/manual/en/regexp.reference.escape.php):

[`access_token=\K[^&\s]+`](https://regex101.com/r/ZtzacZ/1)

```
$pattern = '/access_token=\K[^&\s]+/';
$subject = "https://WBSITE_LINK.com/#access_token=1b6e37716abdh&state=state123&scope=profile%20booking&token_type=bearer&expires_in=15552000";
preg_match($pattern, $subject, $matches);
echo $matches[0];
```

[Output](https://3v4l.org/Ys9qq)